# Restore inheritance of subsite from main site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, permissions, sub-site, inheritance

How do I restore inheritance of subsite from main site?

The permission of a group was prior 'Full Control' and accidentally change it.  Adding and removing links was no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to site settings > site permissions page of subsite
2. You can use this URL format to go to site permissions directly: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/subsite/_layouts/15/user.aspx`
3. Click on "Delete unique permissions" under "PERMISSIONS" tab:

   [image]